# REST Api CORS issue

Tags: php, mongodb, api, rest

I am developing a mobile application that uses js on the frontend and connects to a PHP backend which runs script against MongoDB database to return json data.Now everything was working fine as I tested the whole backend using localhost but now I want to upload the PHP files to some server so that I can test the whole thing using the actual mobile app.

So here's what I have done so far:-

I made my MongoDB database on MongoLab (they have a starter free plan) and I also uploaded my PHP files to google app engine (again for free). But now when I try to call a file using say Postman in google chrome, it shows Access-Allow-Control-Origin error, http://localhost is not allowed. I tried to google to find a solution to this but it didn't prove to be helpful as the error still persists.

So I switched to Amazon aws, fired up an ec2 instance, installed apache and PHP and uploaded my PHP files there, and I got the same Access-Allow-Control-Origin error.

So I guess my real question is can someone just walk me through the process of how I can upload my PHP files and have them connect to MongoDb database and then call them from localhost or from mobile app and have the result given to me.

P.S. - Sorry for such a long post but I just wanted to explain everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost');
```

to the top of any page which has the problem.